# how to get data from localstorage and set state react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage

i have localstorage which has a key "cartProduct" and value that contains an array of object

```
[
{"id":"001",
"productName":"Tesla",
"categories":"car",
"price":1000000,
"quantity": 1
},
{
"id":"002",
"productName":"Honda",
"categories":"motorcycle",
"price":10000,
"quantity": 2
}
]
```

i try to make function to get data from localstorage, set in state and display it in input form, but the data still doesn't appear.

```
function Data() (
  const carts = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cartProduct"));
  const [name, setName] = localStorage.setItem('myData', carts);
    <div>
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder=" product" 
        value={name} //value from productname with id: 001
        onChange={el => setName(el.target.value)}
      />
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="product"
        value={name} //value from productname with id: 002
        onChange={el => setName(el.target.value)}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

but showing and error "localStorage.setItem(...) is undefined"
how to fix it?

Comment: localStorage.setItem() doesn't have a return value: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/setItem so not entirely sure what you are expecting those const values in the destructured array assignment

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to save object into localstorage. you have to convert it to string first. like the following

```
const [name, setName] = localStorage.setItem('myData', JSON.stringify(carts));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const [cards, setCards] = useState(JSON.parse((localStorage.getItem('carts'))));
```

It will work!

Answer (score 0):

localStorage cannot store objects and if you will really do objects will be stored like this.

```
"[object Object],[object Object]"
```

And so you need to convert your objects into JSON string before you save it.

```
let data = [
      {
        "id": "001",
        "productName": "Tesla",
        "categories": "car",
        "price": 1000000,
        "quantity": 1
      },
      {
        "id": "002",
        "productName": "Honda",
        "categories": "motorcycle",
        "price": 10000,
        "quantity": 2
      }
    ]

let jsonString = JSON.stringify(data)
localStorage.setItem('cartProduct', jsonString)
```

and when you will going to retrieve it you can parse it back to JavaScript Object again like this

```
const carts = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cartProduct"));
```

But regarding with your main concern try to use this code :

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
const carts = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cartProduct'));

function Data() {
  const [name, setName] = useState(carts);
  function handleChange(e) {
    const {value} = e.target
    setName(()=> value)
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder=" product"
        value={name} //value from productname with id: 001
        onChange={handleChange}
      />
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="product"
        value={name} //value from productname with id: 002
        onChange={handleChange}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: result of your code is [object object]. then i trying to add
```
value={name[0].productName} //Tesla
value={name[1].productName} //Honda
```
next problem is how to get value wih mapping instead of hard code to get index one by one?
and how to save the changed value to local storage

Comment: Try to retrieve the localStorage in the console and check if you stored it right. Because the question is did you store your data in the localStorage in JSON string format?. type localStorage.getItem('cartProduct') in the browsers console to see if its not "[object Object],[object Object]". If it is then you need to store it  again  to localStorage as JSON string format.